# How to Draw an Arrow between 2 point for ARCGIS ANDROID?

Tags: arcgis-android

I want to develop an android app where i need to draw a arrow line between 2 point.
I know how to draw a line between 2 point.
But can't get any idea to draw an arrow for the same.

```
private void drawPolylineOrPolygon(Point p1,Point p2) {
    Graphic graphic;
    MultiPath multipath = new Polyline();

    // Create and add graphics layer if it doesn't already exist
    if (graphicsLayer == null) {
        graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        mapView.addLayer(graphicsLayer);
    }

    mPoints.add(p1);
    mPoints.add(p2);
    if (mPoints.size() > 0) {
        multipath.startPath(mPoints.get(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < mPoints.size(); i++) {
            multipath.lineTo(mPoints.get(i));
        }
        graphic = new Graphic(multipath, new SimpleLineSymbol(Color.BLACK, 4));
        graphicsLayer.addGraphic(graphic);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? where are you stuck? you are bound to get more help if you show the research that you have already done.

Comment: If you have created a line feature between two points, shouldn't the layer symbol for that feature class  (set to an appropriate arrow marker) be enough?

Comment: GISI I am new to Arcgis Android so dont have any idea about what you are saying.

Comment: Guys any kind of help will be appreciated.I really need to do this thing eagerly.

Answer (score 1):

please check this url
https://coderanch.com/t/340443/java/Draw-arrow-head-line

```
...   
private double phi= Math.toRadians(30);
private int barb=20;
...
   private void drawArrow(List<GPSLocationModel> locationModelList) {
    Point firstWGSPoint=locationModelList.get(locationModelList.size()-2).getLocation();
    Point secondWGSPoint=locationModelList.get(locationModelList.size()-1).getLocation();
    Point firstMapPoint = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(firstWGSPoint,SpatialReference.create(4326),mapView.getSpatialReference());
    Point secondMapPoint = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(secondWGSPoint,SpatialReference.create(4326),mapView.getSpatialReference());

    Point firstScreenPoint=mapView.toScreenPoint(firstMapPoint);
    Point secondScreenPoint=mapView.toScreenPoint(secondMapPoint);
    List<Point> arrowPointList=createArrowPointlist(firstScreenPoint,secondScreenPoint);
    List<Point> arrowGeomPointList=new ArrayList<Point>();
    for(int i=0;i<arrowPointList.size();i++){
        Point point=arrowPointList.get(i);
        Point geomPoint=  mapView.toMapPoint((float) point.getX(),(float) point.getY());
        arrowGeomPointList.add(geomPoint);
    }
    SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(Color.GREEN, 3, SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE.SOLID);
    Polyline strightLine=new Polyline();
    strightLine.startPath(firstMapPoint);
    Graphic stLineGraphic = new Graphic(strightLine, lineSymbol);
    strightLine.lineTo(secondMapPoint);
    this.addGraphic(stLineGraphic);

    Polyline arrowLine=new Polyline();
    for(int i=0;i<arrowGeomPointList.size()-1;i++){
        Point startPoint=arrowGeomPointList.get(i);
        Point endPoint  =arrowGeomPointList.get(i+1);
        arrowLine.startPath(startPoint);
        arrowLine.lineTo(endPoint);
    }

    Graphic arrowLineGraphic = new Graphic(arrowLine, lineSymbol);
    this.addGraphic(arrowLineGraphic);
}

private List<Point> createArrowPointlist(Point secondScreenPoint, Point firstScreenPoint) {
    List<Point> arrowPointList=new ArrayList<Point>();
    double dy =  firstScreenPoint.getY()-secondScreenPoint.getY();
    double dx =  firstScreenPoint.getX()-secondScreenPoint.getX();
    double theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    //System.out.println("theta = " + Math.toDegrees(theta));
    double rho = theta + phi;
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        double x, y;
        x = firstScreenPoint.getX() - barb * Math.cos(rho);
        y = firstScreenPoint.getY() - barb * Math.sin(rho);
        rho = theta - phi;
        arrowPointList.add(firstScreenPoint);
        arrowPointList.add(new Point(x,y));

    }
   return arrowPointList;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please [edit] your answer to include some explanation for your solution - what it does and where to use it etc.